# The use of a lightbox and the click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm using a lightbox for image viewing and I just have to use `rel="lightbox"` inside `<a>`. The problem is that my site has AJAX for every link, so I coded:

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

This way, every link turns to be an AJAX request. What is pissing me off is that when I don't make any request, the lightbox works properly, but as soon as I click in a link to make the AJAX request and then click in an image, the lightbox doesn't work.

I know that the problem is the Lightbox which isn't adding the click event once another request is done. It happens when I use `$('a').click()` instead of  `$('a').live()`

But I don't know how to fix. Maybe I have to change the lightbox for one which adds click events?

Help!

Comment: It might be handy to know which lightbox plugin!

Comment: Can you post the code where you're rigging up the lightbox? (Also, I assume these links are inside `#content`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the lightbox to Top Up lightbox and it worked perfectly. Probably, the older one wouldn't create event listeners using `.live()` 'because of AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a:not(a[rel~="lightbox")').live('click', function() {
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```